# Given an existing Flux (FluxMap), how can I emit message to this Flux?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Our project use a external library. It has a method return FluxMap (since FluxMap is not completely public so just call it Flux):

```
Flux<MappedType> aFluxMap = Library.createMappingToMappedType();
```

I have to emit some objects to aFluxMap to get them converted to MappedType (it has private constructor, few setter), then I can:

```
aFluxMap.doOnNext(converted -> doJob(converted))
```

I expect that there is a method on Flux/Mono like:

```
aFluxMap.emit(myObj);
```

But I could not find any method like that.

I have searched "how to emit to flux dynamically", then there is a solution:

```
FluxProcessor p = UnicastProcessor.create().serialize();
FluxSink sink = p.sink();
sink.next(mess);
```

But seem that it emit to newly created flux (p), not my aFluxMap. So I want to ask is there any way to emit message to a existed Flux (or how to connect a FluxSink to a existed Flux, so that whenever FluxSink .next(mess), then the existed Flux get the message). Thank you

Note: please don't pay much attention to the stupidity of the library. We must use it

==========================================

UPDATE:
As @lkatiforis suggestion:

```
FluxProcessor p = //see above
Flux<MappedType> aFluxMap = Library.createMappingToMappedType();
p.flatMap(raw -> aFluxMap).subscribe();
```

I got another issue. `Library.createMappingToMappedType()`  return a subscribed Flux with its source is UnicastProcessor (also subscribed).

When I call `p.flatMap(raw -> aFluxMap)`, then internally aFluxMap get subscribed again cause its source also get subscribed again, so that I got an exception telling that "UnicastProcessor can be subscribe once". Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new stream and then merge the two streams into one by using one of these methods: [merge](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#merge-int-org.reactivestreams.Publisher...-), [concat](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#concat-java.lang.Iterable-), [zip](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#zip-java.util.function.Function-int-org.reactivestreams.Publisher...-), and their variants.

Here is an example:

```java
    Flux<MappedType> yourFlux = //...
    Flux<MappedType> aFluxMap = Library.createMappingToMappedType();
    Flux.merge(aFluxMap, yourFlux);
```

The merge operator executes a merging of the MappedType objects from the two provided publisher sequences.

Comment: I don't really get your point. You mean merge what to what? Btw can we use flatmap?

Comment: @SoT edit made.

Comment: I made an update, hope that you can help me

Comment: This is a completely different question please create new question.